# How can I avoid frequently querying the same fields without resorting to using a temp table?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

So I have the following query (obfuscated for security reasons) but it takes hours to run:

```
SELECT  t.apple as APPLE,
        t.orange as ORANGE,
        t.kiwi as KIWI
FROM    table_in_linked_db@db_link t
WHERE (t.pear = 'FOO' OR t.grape  = 'BAR') 
AND     t.apple NOT IN 
            (SELECT val 
             FROM   table_in_my_db
             WHERE  type = 'APPLE')
OR      t.orange NOT IN 
            (SELECT val 
             FROM   table_in_my_db 
             WHERE  type = 'ORANGE');
```

Normally, in other languages, I would create a temp table here at the beginning containing the values from `table_in_my_db` to avoid having to query and iterate through it for every row in `table_in_linked_db`. But from what I've read, creating and destroying temp tables is bad practice in Oracle SQL as only the data is temporary.

Does anyone know of an alternative I can use? Possibly by rewriting my existing query?

Comment: Do you have access to the remote database? can you make any changes to it?

Comment: @pmdba I only have read access

Comment: Indexing and creating a materialized view are your basic options.

Comment: you could use a fast refresh materialized view to hold the data locally, if you could get the remote database to create a materialized view log on the source table... and you're right: including DDL operations (like create/drop table) in application code is considered extremely bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try adding the following index to the table inside the subqueries:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON table_in_my_db (type, val);
```

This should let Oracle evaluate the two subqueries very quickly, thereby boosting the performance of the overall query.